# ckeditor in gwt throw Access denied (ie browser)

Tags: java, gwt, ckeditor

Использую ckeditor в gwt проекте. При попытке уничтожить ckeditor вызываю функцию destroy, но в gwt дебаггере выскакивает такого рода ошибка

`com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error) @com.companyname.projectname.frontend.client.common.widgets.CKEditorWidget::destroyEditor()([]): Разрешение отклонено`

Такая проблема возникает только в IE.